# Excel formula creating dynamic string manipulation for (RIGHT,MID and LEFT)

Tags: excel, formula

I have this table below:

[image]

What I am trying to achieve is that, I want to have a dynamic formula to get only the strings after the dashed. The first String before the dash has fixed length so I think there could be a more dynamic way of getting the last string rather than doing it manually as my current formula below.

I have less date now so I am okay with that but soon it would be more time consuming if I don't look for an immediate solution.I current create different formula each row and I need only 1 formula to drag down and do the job.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Instead of a screenshot, can you copy/paste your table here (formatting with the code tags `{}`). That way we can copy/paste in to Excel without having to manually enter.

Comment: I will try it the next time I have question, but nice advise also saved time for attaching image :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try,

```
=replace(e2, 1, find("-", e2), "")
```

Comment: Woah, clever. I will have to remember this, it's much cleaner (IMO) than my Right/Len/Search mix.

Comment: Given the static length of the first section that the op claims, the Find operation isn't really necessary.

Comment: I want to have this answer but BruceWayne commented first but this is awesome!

Comment: I will use this one since Find is not necessary but thanks BruceWayne

Comment: @BrandonJakeSullano - It's your question, you can decide on whatever answer best fits what you were working on.  If you think Jeeped's answer is better for whatever reason, feel free to mark it as The Answer.  I'm more than happy to "lose" rep to Jeeped :D

Comment: Both are valid responses; choose your preference and flip a coin for anything else.

Comment: Thanks Guys Good night, I can sleep now! (IMO)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Right()` combined with `Search()`:

```
=RIGHT(E2,LEN(E2)-SEARCH("-",E2))
```

<sub>Edited to update to match OP's formula references</sub>

Comment: The result is #VALUE!

Comment: @BrandonJakeSullano - Did you update `A1` to be whatever cell you need (I suppose `E2`)?

Comment: I did not LOL yeah its now working, I am new on this kind of formula looks complicated but it does the job since you are the first one to comment I will grab your answer!!